# What does this code do? do I have only one string named menu? or various strings that can be access by the label menu?

Tags: assembly

```
data segment    
menu db "Please select a choice:" ,13, 10  ; 13, 10= New Line 
     db "1. Jogar",13,10
     db "2. Carregar",13,10
     db "3. Guardar",13,10 
     db "4. Top 5" ,13,10  
     db "5. Creditos",13,10      
     db "6. Exit",13,10,'$'

ends
```

I can't understand this syntax
And also how can I make a function that takes the number (and only the number as input) and if the user selects any other character it shows this menu again until the program gets one of these numbers

Comment: It's a single string having embedded CR LF so multiple lines when displayed.

Comment: *also how can I make a function that does all these different things* is a separate question, and should be in its own post. However, it's far too vague and broad in scope, so it wouldn't be acceptable here. You need to do your own homework. You'll find your experiences here will be much better if you spend some time taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages to learn how the site works before you begin posting.

Answer (score 2):

You only have one string named Menu. As far as DOS is concerned, the string isn't over until the `$` is reached. If you want each of those to be its own string with a different label for easy access, you can do this:

```
data segment    
menu db "Please select a choice:" ,13, 10  ; 13, 10= New Line
 
menu_1 db "1. Jogar",13,10,'$'
menu_2 db "2. Carregar",13,10,'$'
menu_3 db "3. Guardar",13,10,'$'
menu_4 db "4. Top 5" ,13,10,'$'
menu_5 db "5. Creditos",13,10,'$'  
menu_6 db "6. Exit",13,10,'$'

ends
```

That being said, by doing this the extra '$' at the end of each does take up a little more space. But it's more convenient if at some point you decide you want to print half the menu or something like that. If you're always going to print the entire menu, leave it the way you had it.

Comment: Isn't it MS-DOS `int 21h` calls that look for a `$` terminator?  I thought `int 10h` BIOS calls  used different terminators.  Or `ah=13h` / `int 10h` takes an explicit-length buffer.  (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INT_10H).  So I'd have said "DOS", not "DOS BIOS".

Comment: You're probably right, I forgot exactly how strings work  in DOS. I always just wrote my own that looked for a null byte anyway so that's probably why I forgot which was which.

Comment: Yeah, I'm sure DOS strings are a `$` terminator, at least for the most commonly-used write-string system call.  http://spike.scu.edu.au/~barry/interrupts.html#ah09 .  Apparently even open file (`int 21h` / AH=3Dh) takes a zero-terminated string.  Comments on [Why did DOS use dollar-terminated strings?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/21797) say that output-string was the only case where DOS used a `$` terminator.  Seems like a really silly choice, a legacy of some character set used by CP/M but not DOS.